# HSSFHyperlink and URL fragment encoding

Tags: excel, hyperlink, apache-poi, url-encoding, poi-hssf

I am using the apache poi package to generate excel workbooks.  In the workbook I include cells with hyperlinks, using URLs containing fragments (#frag).  In the resulting cells, the # character in the url has been encoded which makes it a different URL.

My question: Is there any way to preserve the URL provided as is?

My code:

```
        Cell cell = row.createCell(index);
        cell.setCellValue("the link");
        HSSFHyperlink link = workbook.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_URL);
        link.setAddress("http://localhost:3000/#/search/pattern");
        cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

The url opened in the browser after clicking on the link in the generated spreadsheet

```
http://localhost:3000/%23/search/pattern
```

Any pointer appreciated.

Comment: I have tried your code and Apache POI is not changing the `#` to `%23`. If you see the excel file and do 'Edit Hyperlink', you will see that the url does have a `#`. Its the browser that resolves `#` to `%23`

Comment: You are correct the issue is not with the library.  I now see that the excel replacement I am using has the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue about #value -> %23..

 
so i use this. "setCellFormula"

```
String link = "http://localhost:3000/#/search/pattern";
Cell cell = row.createCell(index);
cell.setCellFormula("HYPERLINK(\""+link+"\", \"link\")");
```

Comment: Great answer, however, did you encounter an issue with the Protected View? When I use the HYPERLINK function and download excel file from browser (it opens excel in Protected View mode) cell appears to be "0". But when I change mode to Editing, cell value becomes correct and clickable